# MySQL Create View: Varchar converted to Blob while doing union

Tags: mysql, view, blob, union

I've created a view like this using a union of 4 tables.

```
   CREATE VIEW `con_dataset_v` AS select `d`.`VALUE_ID` AS `VALUE_ID`,`d`.`SET_NAME` AS `SET_NAME`,`d`.`SET_TYPE` AS `SET_TYPE`,`d`.`VALUE` AS `VALUE`,`d`.`DISPLAY_VALUE` AS `DISPLAY_VALUE` from `con_dataset` `d` 

union 

select `s`.`SUBJECT_ID` AS `VALUE_ID`,_utf8'CONVO_SUBJECT' AS `SET_NAME`,NULL AS `SET_TYPE`,`s`.`SUBJECT_NAME` AS `VALUE`,concat(`s`.`SUBJECT_NAME`,_utf8' (',`s`.`SUBJECT_DESC`,_utf8')') AS `DISPLAY_VALUE` from `con_subject` `s` 

union 

select `t`.`TOPIC_ID` AS `VALUE_ID`,_utf8'CONVO_TOPIC' AS `SET_NAME`,`t`.`SUBJECT_ID` AS `SET_TYPE`,`t`.`TOPIC_NAME` AS `VALUE`,concat(`t`.`TOPIC_NAME`,_utf8' (',`t`.`TOPIC_DESC`,_utf8')') AS `DISPLAY_VALUE` from `con_topic` `t` 

union 

select `l`.`LOC_ID` AS `VALUE_ID`,_utf8'LOCATION' AS `SET_NAME`,`l`.`COUNTRY` AS `SET_TYPE`,`l`.`LOCATION` AS `VALUE`,concat(`l`.`LOCATION`,_utf8', ',`l`.`STATE`,_utf8', ',`l`.`COUNTRY`) AS `DISPLAY_VALUE` from `con_location` `l`;
```

When I query the view, the colum SET_TYPE is appearing as BLOB while in all tables I used, the columns are Varchars ranging from 45 length to 500 length.

When I do a join of only 3 tables, It looks fine - SET_TYPE is varchar.

What could be wrong with a union of 4 tables?

Appreciate your help.

**Update:** Table definitions

CON_DATASET

```
'VALUE_ID', 'varchar(30)', 'NO', 'PRI', '', ''
'SET_NAME', 'varchar(45)', 'NO', 'MUL', '', ''
'SET_TYPE', 'varchar(45)', 'YES', '', '', ''
'VALUE', 'varchar(250)', 'NO', '', '', ''
'DISPLAY_VALUE', 'varchar(250)', 'NO', '', '', ''
```

CON_SUBJECT

```
'SUBJECT_ID', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'PRI', '', ''
'SUBJECT_NAME', 'varchar(45)', 'NO', '', '', ''
'SUBJECT_DESC', 'varchar(500)', 'YES', '', '', ''
```

CON_TOPIC

```
'TOPIC_ID', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'PRI', '', ''
'SUBJECT_ID', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', 'PRI', '', ''
'TOPIC_NAME', 'varchar(45)', 'NO', '', '', ''
'TOPIC_DESC', 'varchar(500)', 'YES', '', '', ''
```

CON_LOCATION

```
'LOC_ID', 'int(10) unsigned', 'NO', '', '', ''
'LOCATION', 'varchar(250)', 'NO', 'PRI', '', ''
'STATE', 'varchar(250)', 'NO', 'PRI', '', ''
'COUNTRY', 'varchar(250)', 'NO', 'PRI', '', ''
```

Comment: Show your tables definitions - CREATE TABLE.

Comment: Is it any particular query being unioned in that triggers this (eg, maybe the one that specifies NULL for that column)

Comment: None. As soon as I create this view and query "select * from con_dataset_v where set_type is not null" - it lists the records but with BLOB data. I have to click on the 'view' image in MySQL Query browser to see the BLOB data for SET_TYPE.

Comment: the data types of the columns used for SET_TYPE vary. Cast them all the varchar.